# Tips? Where is the best current installation, setup & best practice documentation for a Debian web server? MySQL, PHP5, Mail etc

Tags: debian

I'm just looking at installing a Debian production server and would like any helpful links to documentation.

You know how things change so fast. I'm likely to be looking for whole sub-systems that have been deprecated.

Useful links:
http://www.debian.org/doc/
http://wiki.debian.org/
[LAMP install: Apache Mysql PHP(http://wiki.debian.org/LaMp)](http://wiki.debian.org/LaMpLinux)
http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/
http://www.howtoforge.com/

```
sudo aptitude install vim 
sudo update-alternatives --config editor (then select vim.basic)
update-rc.d service defaults (setting runlevels for programmes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian doesn't tend to take too much of a stand on things like which particular program you should be using to perform a particular task.  Your best bet to see what's "new and improved" (and how things should now be done) for Debian-specific tools like the package manager and installer is to read up on the release notes for the release(s) that you're not previously familiar with.  The release notes for the recently released 5.0, for example, are at http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/releasenotes

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I believe it would be helpful to take a look on some tutorials on [HowtoForge](http://www.howtoforge.com/) also. For example: [Virtual Users And Domains With Postfix, Courier And MySQL (+ SMTP-AUTH, Quota, SpamAssassin, ClamAV)](http://www.howtoforge.com/virtual_postfix_mysql_quota_courier)